# javascript wait for file upload to process before taking action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file input that's masked by some text to make it look nicer.  I'm trying to find a way, once the user has begun the file upload, to wait until we actually have the file before continuing.

```
<form id="pm_uploadForm" method="POST">
  <input type="file" id="fileinput" onchange="loadFile(event)" 
  style="display:none"/>
  <p id="upload_file">Click here to upload your file.</p>
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

In my script section, I have the following code:  This first one triggers the actual `file` input element:

```
$(document).on('click', '#upload_file', function() {
  $("#fileinput").trigger('click');
});
```

and this links to the `onchange` event for that input:

```
loadFile = function(event) {
   console.log("loading file...");
   setTimeout(function(){  
     new_file_name = event.target.value.split("\\")[2];
    // do stuff with the file...  
   }, 5000);
}
```

Right now - the only way I can make sure the event finishes before the `do stuff with the file...` lines is to use a `setTimeout` function, which is not good.  If the file the user is uploading is 500kb, that's fine - but if it's 15mb, I execute the code before the file is finished uploading.

How do I wait for the upload to finish prior to running code on that uploaded file?

Comment: Yeah but the file isn't really uploaded, it's just allocated within the page and waiting for  uploading. It should be ready on the change event.

Comment: which change event?

Comment: Depends on how you upload the file - form submit or ajax?